# shuffle random MYSQL results

Tags: php, mysql

The following code displays random database images as well as one specific image (which is what I want). How can I shuffle these results after database query as image ID 11 is always displayed first? I want image ID 11 displayed randomly amongst the others.

Can I use SHUFFLE(). If so where exactly do I put it as at the moment?

Any help would be appreciated as still learning PHP

Thanks.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("images") or die(mysql_error()) ;


$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `profile_images` ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT 7");


while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){ ?>

<div style="width:300px;">


<img src="<? echo $get_photo['url']; ?>">


</div>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: while($get_photo[]=mysql_fetch_array($photo));
shuffle($get_photo);

FYI : Never use rand() in mysql db if you have more that 200k results.  It will slow your application.

Comment: @Aby He has got a `LIMIT 7` so I doubt it'll be slow.

Comment: thanks for correcting me.  Need to add this If the query is related to "order by rand()"

Comment: @shiplu, ordering comes before limiting. Think about it, how can it possibly determine the first row until it has called rand for all rows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can shuffle them after they are retrieved to php.

```
$photos = array();
while ($get_photo = mysql_fetch_array($photo))
    $photos[] = $get_photo;

shuffle($photos);
```

Or you can do it with subqueries:

```
SELECT A.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `profile_images` 
    ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
    LIMIT 7
) as A
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 10):

Its doesnt need to be that complicated if you just put for example

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_table ORDER BY RAND()
```

This will randomise your data. if you want to limit out how many images you show then just put:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 4):

1. First select the specific image then union other 6 images collected by random.
2. **When you sort something by `rand()` all the rows get unique random value to sort so the subgroups aren't sorted**. So using more columns in order by clause does not work if there is `rand()` present.  Hence I have used alias the result and sort it again.

See the query

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM   `profile_images` 
 WHERE  id = 11 
 LIMIT  1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * 
 FROM   (SELECT * 
         FROM   `profile_images` 
         WHERE  id != 11 
         ORDER  BY Rand() 
         LIMIT  6) `t` 
 ORDER  BY id DESC)
```

Comment: Have tried your select query but am now getting error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in....which is line 27 th ewhile loop: while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){?>

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in....line 27.

Comment: Error message = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') UNION (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `profile_images` WHERE id != 11 O' at line 1

Comment: this is the SQL using: $photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   `profile_images` WHERE  id = 11 LIMIT  1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM   (SELECT * FROM   `profile_images` WHERE  ID != 11 ORDER  BY Rand()  LIMIT  6) `t` ORDER  BY id DESC");

Comment: You are missing the first parenthesis `(` there. It's just before the first select.

Comment: thanks. Got rid of that error but now getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in....line 16 which is still the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

First select the image with ID 11 and than query the rest with UNION keyword

```
SELECT *
FROM Images
Where ID = 11
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Images
WHERE ID != 11
```