# Randomise friend's list widget

Tags: socialengine

i have been on this for a few hours,

I want to randomise the result and there has been not provision to do that from the backend.

```
<?php foreach( $this->friends as $membership ):
if( !isset($this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id]) ) continue;
$member = $this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id];
?>

<li id="user_friend_<?php echo $member->getIdentity() ?>">

  <?php echo $this->htmlLink($member->getHref(), $this->itemPhoto($member, 'thumb.icon'), array('class' => 'profile_friends_icon')) ?>

   <div class='profile_friends_body'>
    <div class='profile_friends_status'>
      <span>
        <?php echo $this->htmlLink($member->getHref(), $member->getTitle()) ?>
      </span>
      <?php //echo $member->status; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if( $this->viewer()->isSelf($this->subject()) && Engine_Api::_()->getApi('settings', 'core')->getSetting('user.friends.lists')): // BEGIN LIST CODE ?>
      <div class='profile_friends_lists' id='user_friend_lists_<?php echo $member->user_id ?>'>

        <span class="pulldown" style="display:inline-block;" onClick="toggleFriendsPulldown(event, this, '<?php echo $member->user_id ?>');">
          <div class="pulldown_contents_wrapper">
            <div class="pulldown_contents">
              <ul>
                <?php foreach( $this->lists as $list ):
                  $inList = in_array($list->list_id, (array)@$this->listsByUser[$member->user_id]);
                  ?>
                  <li class="<?php echo ( $inList !== false ? 'friend_list_joined' : 'friend_list_unjoined' ) ?> user_profile_friend_list_<?php echo $list->list_id ?>" onclick="handleFriendList(event, $(this), '<?php echo $member->user_id ?>', '<?php echo $list->list_id ?>');">
                    <span>
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteFriendList(event, <?php echo $list->list_id ?>);">x</a>
                    </span>
                    <div>
                      <?php echo $list->title ?>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <li>
                  <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->translate('New list...') ?>" onclick="new Event(event).stop();" onkeypress="if( new Event(event).key == 'enter' ) { createFriendList(event, $(this), '<?php echo $member->user_id ?>'); }" />
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $this->translate('add to list') ?></a>
        </span>

      </div>

    <?php endif; // END LIST CODE ?>
  </div>
   <div class='profile_friends_options'>
     <?php echo $this->userFriendship($member) ?>
   </div>

</li>
```

and need to randomise the result..
I have tried using the

```
rand()
```

but that seem abortive.
Any help please

Comment: rand() just gives a random number, you want to sort your array by random keys. So try shuffle($this->friends)

Comment: Thanks Tom.. I used this `foreach( shuffle($this->friends) as $membership ):
  
    if( !isset($this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id]) ) continue;
    $member = $this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id];` but it didn't do the work.. the widget could not be rendered

Comment: I have also tried this `shuffle($this->friends);
  foreach( $this->friends as $membership ):
    if( !isset($this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id]) ) continue;
    $member = $this->friendUsers[$membership->resource_id];` but not working

Comment: Maybe the table is too "specific". Try: print_r($this->friends) before and after shuffle($this->friends) to see if it actually shuffled the array. If not then you will have to use usort() with custom ordering function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457029/shuffle-random-mysql-results check this