# How do I display a random text and image taken from a MySQL Database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, random

I'm currently working on creating a page that will display a random image and text compiled into a MySQL database. So far I've got this:

```
<?php 

     //This is the directory where images will be saved 
     $target = "images/"; 
     $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

     //This gets all the other information from the form 
     $name=$_POST['name'];  
     $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

     // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("mysite.com", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
     mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

     //Writes the information to the database 
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `employees` VALUES ('$name', '$pic')") ; 

     //Writes the photo to the server 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
     { 

     //Tells you if its all ok 
     echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
     } 
     else { 

     //Gives and error if its not 
     echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
     } 
     ?>
```

The form works fine with this and submits the pictures to the MySQL database giving me both the picture and the text.

Using VARCHAR(30) for each variable.

I was wondering how to go about creating an HTML/PHP page that displays random text and a random image from this database.

Let me know if you can help!

Comment: Haven't got a lot of time right now, but take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457029/shuffle-random-mysql-results). It aims to shuffle your database results ultimately achieving randomization. Regardless, you might also want to seek to make your script invulnerable... you're saving unfiltered user content => possible XSS injection => session hijacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this simple code:

```
<?php

  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

  while($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    echo $rand['name'];
    echo $rand['pic'];
  }

?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nothing is being displayed. I copy and pasted this code onto the separate webpage where I want it to be displayed yet nothing is being displayed from the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what do you mean by random, do you mean any one of the images from the databases?

Also if you could provide some information about how are storing the images in the database as blobs or something else, this might help to give you a better answer.

Comment: Using VARCHAR(30) for each variable.
I mean random as in displaying a random image alongside a random piece of text both taken from the MySQL database. So each time you refresh the page there will be a random image and line of text from the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

you can using rand();

```
SELECT * FROM employees
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

use php to proces this query
```

hope this query can help you

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;

```
 Solution 2:
 $offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `table` ");
 $offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result ); 
 $offset = $offset_row->offset;
 $result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $offset, 1 " );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Would up vote, but I don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Order by Rand in your query, however, this is very bad for performance!

Another option would be to add an id field (if you haven't already) to you table and set it as a `Primary Key` and `Auto Incrament`, so you columns would look like `id | name | pic` - this is a standard practice anyway.

Then either:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees");

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $data[] = $row;
} 

$rand - rand(0, $count);
$imageData = $data[$rand];
//This would give you a random entry
```

Other wise (So you not grabbing all the data from the table).

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM employees");
$rand = rand(1, $count);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$rand");
//The issue with this one is you have have deleted a row, so you have to check for that
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Would up vote but I've only been here for a bit - need more reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: Cheers, dude. If this answered your question could you always tick (accept) it. :)