# Is it possible to select a random column in one row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example  I have 1 question and 5 answers.

**Question:**

```
5+5=?

Answer:

a. 3
b. 4
c. 5
d. 9
e. 10
```

**Here's the sample data in the database**

```
id  |  question  |  ans1  |  asn2  |  ans3  | ans4  |  correctAns  |
1   |  5+5       |    3   |    4   |    5   |   9   |      10      |
```

I want to randomize the output of the ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, and the correctAns.

is it possible? if it is please guide me.. Thanks

Comment: You can grab all the answers from MySQL and tell php to show a random one for that question

Comment: Just put them all in 1 array and shuffle it..

Comment: HINT: `WHERE $id = $rand` would be a part of your query and you will change `$rand` randomly.

Comment: Can you show me the code sir? Sorry for trouble sir Im still newbie in php.

Comment: Really bad structure for such case. Why columns? What if you'll have 15 answers for choosing?

Comment: That's a very nice question Alma, it helps the OP understand their own mistake in a very easy counter question

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes. Point is: bad design leads to bad solutions. Anyway, question has academic interest for me, so posted an answer

Comment: @AlmaDo Would you suggest a `Question` table and an `Answer` table with the `Answer` table having a foreign key into the `Question` table?

Comment: @Cruncher - like that. (I've mentioned that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21875640/2637490))

Answer (score 10):

**Structure notes**

While this question *may be* interesting, use-case with answers to question and provided structure is really bad. That is because you are restricted to certain amount of answers. That means:

- All questions will have to have all answers. If some question should have only 2 answers for choosing, then - yes, there will be N-2 `NULL` values (here `N` means number of answers, in case above `N=4`)
- If only *one* question will have to have more than `N` answers - then, yes, `ALTER` awaits. And that will produce more `NULL`-s for all other questions.

I recommend to change your structure. Store answers in separate table with foreign key to parent questions table. That will be enough (and, besides, question about random selection would be much easier to resolve)

**Question solution**

However, questions that involve table structure may be interesting to deal with - and in MySQL, such questions are classically resolved via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` meta-data. To solve the issue with SQL only, you'll need to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Here's sample table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------------+
| id   | question | ans1 | ans2 | ans3 | ans4 | correctAns |
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------------+
|    1 | 5+5      |    3 |    4 |    5 |    9 |         10 |
+------+----------+------+------+------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I assume columns `id` and `question` as to be included always in first and second place to result. Other columns should be randomized. To do this, you can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) table:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT id, question, ', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 
    ' FROM test') AS s 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME='test' 
    AND 
    TABLE_SCHEMA='test' 
    AND 
    COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'question') 
  ORDER BY RAND()) AS randCols;
```

As you can see, this SQL will produce another SQL. Result will be like:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| s                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT id, question, ans1,ans2,correctAns,ans4,ans3 FROM test |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So this you can easily use in prepared statement. Prepare variable:

```
mysql> set @s=(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT id, question, ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ' FROM test') AS s FROM (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='test' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'question') ORDER BY RAND()) AS randCols);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Use it for statement:

```
mysql> prepare stmt from @s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared
```

And, finally, execute it:

```
mysql> execute stmt;
+------+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | question | correctAns | ans1 | ans2 | ans4 | ans3 |
+------+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | 5+5      |         10 |    3 |    4 |    9 |    5 |
+------+----------+------------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's better to first get the result and put it in an array, and then you can shuffle that easily, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ans1, asn2, ans3, ans4, correctAns FROM table_name WHERE id=1";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$answers = mysql_fetch_array($res);
shuffle($answers);
```

Then, iterate through `$answers` as per normal.

Comment: Answer got the benefit of PHP tag both in simplicity and efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

For a pure mysql answer:

```
SELECT ans FROM
(SELECT ans1 as ans,questionid FROM questions)
UNION
(SELECT ans2 as ans,questionid FROM questions)
UNION
(SELECT ans3 as ans,questionid FROM questions)
UNION
(SELECT ans4 as ans,questionid FROM questions)
UNION
(SELECT correct as ans,questionid FROM questions)
WHERE questionid = $questionid
ORDER BY RAND()
```

the order by rand() is used the make the order of rows returned random

**Better way**

A better way to do it is change your column structure to:

Table Question:

```
| id | name |
```

Table anser:

```
| question_id | answer |
```

With data:

```
id   | name
1    | 5+5

question_id | answer
1           | 4
1           | 3
1           | 9
1           | 5
1           | 10
```

then you could use:

```
SELECT answer
FROM answer
WHERE question_id = $question_id
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() can be a very bad idea - it can be very slow under some (most) conditions.  If you decide to go this route then it would be strongly advised to benchmark your performance and simulate a real world dataset as usually the larger the table grows the greater the performance hit.  It is almost always quicker to either randomize it via application logic or to select specific random identifiers from a previously selected list

Comment: In case of multiplechoice questions I wouldn't be too concerned about performance, how many answers per question can there be. But a valid point nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: Totally agree, I didn't want to take anything away from your answer but thought it was both valid and useful to point out - especially if the OP then uses the same method to then expand the application and start selecting possible questions in a random order etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function.

Use a code similar to:

```
$sql = "select ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4  from questions where id=$questionId";
$result = $mysqliconnection->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
shuffle($row);
```

Now, `row`  contains a shuffled array of results for question with given `id`.

Comment: More about this PHP function [Shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle). You give it an array as the parameter. This will mutate the array as a side note, meaning it will modify the source array.

Using this 'shuffled' array and print it out using your template/view and create an HTML form.

Comment: This will not work. First you put the result in an array to be shuffled.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457029/shuffle-random-mysql-results

Comment: @Mubo , I don't understand why you say it will not work... Could you please explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Oscar , you either use fetch the result from  mysql as an array using 'mysqli fetch_assoc' or put it in  a normal array to be shuffled. I hope you get my point

Comment: @Mubo you're right! I'm going to correct it. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all the answers for that question like

```
$query="SELECT ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,correctAns FROM yourTable WHERE id=1";
```

And then just tell PHP to display a random answer.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$randomAnswer=$row[rand(0,4)];
echo $randomAnswer;
```