# Shuffling data in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables that are connected

Table 1 named "question"

```
Q_ID | C_ID | Question    | Answer
1    | 1    |Question_1   | Answer_1
```

Table 2 named "answer"

```
ID | Q_ID | C_ID | Answer_A        | Answer_B        | Answer_C
1  | 1    | 1    | Dummy Answer 1  | Dummy Answer 2  | Dummy Answer 3
```

and Table 3 named "category" where it's the one that connects all the table and heres my code in fetching the data to be displayed in my html

```
select question.answer, answer.answer_a, answer.answer_b, answer.answer_c from question INNER JOIN answer ON question.q_id = answer.q_id where category.c_id=1
```

What I want to get is to shuffle the answers like

```
a. Dummy Answers 1   b. Dummy Answer 3   c. Answer_1   d. Dummy Answers 2
```

Comment: Design problem - the columns Answer_A,... should've been separate rows. It would've been so easy then.

Comment: @GurV i get what you're saying. so i'm going to have a table named Answer A, Answer B, Answer C, and Answer D?

Comment: This is an interesting project, let us know if you have a question! When you do ask a question, please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Same table, different rows

Comment: @GurV there is no need to store the letter...

Comment: @Shadow i tried rand() but nothing happens. for now, thats what i've got with me.

Comment: @shadow - You're absolutely right. No need of that.

Comment: @GurV then how can i get the correct answer if i combine them in one table? what will the indicator?

Comment: @Vincent do you want the result in same sequence or it could be random?

Comment: @sheetal the result should be randomized.

Comment: did you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9457074/5331171

Comment: @sheetal I will try that. If ever, is there any other way except storing them in an array?

Comment: you can use ORDER BY RAND() in your sql query

Comment: you need to join with your `category table` also since you included it in `where clause` otherwise it will give sql error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY RAND() to randomize your result

```
SELECT question.answer, answer.answer_a, answer.answer_b, answer.answer_c from question 
INNER JOIN answer ON question.q_id = answer.c_id 
INNER JOIN answer on category.c_id = answer.q_id 
WHERE category.c_id=1 ORDER BY RAND()
```

Check this [link](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) for more description

Comment: what is this category where it is added in your sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you'd use [this ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrLOa.png), it'd be easier to select and shuffle the questions whilst still knowing which one is correct.

So there's one "question" table which just contains the question, and an "answer" table which contains all possible answers for a question, and you can flag the correct one.

In the example, if you want to select the answers in a random order, you can just do this: `SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = ? ORDER BY RAND()`. replace the question mark with the question id and you're set.